# getting "unexpectedly found nil" AFTER performing nil check

Tags: swift, swift2

Despite checking for nil, I am getting `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` the error is being caught in the conditional (first line below)

```
if (obj.prop != nil && obj.prop?.otherprop != nil) {
    anotherObj.yetanotherprop = (obj.prop?.otherprop as NSURL).absoluteString
}
```

I have also tried this with `if let` as follows (xcode highlights the 2nd let as being where the unexpected nil is found):

```
if let objA = obj.prop,
    let otherProp = objA.otherPROP {
    anotherObj.yetanotherprop = (otherProp as NSURL).absoluteString
}
```

Why don't either of these work?!

I am getting the source object (`obj` in both cases above) from a 3rd party library that is written in objective c. I am suspecting that I am checking for nil wrong somehow?

Comment: What is the 3rd party library that are you using?

Comment: I cannot discuss the third party library, but I am storing these objects locally in a realm db via realmswift

Answer (score 0):

So in writing this up I think I sort of figured it out. I don't knwo why the first one doesn't work, but the second works as:

```
if let objA = obj.prop,
    let otherProp = objA?.otherPROP {
    anotherObj.yetanotherprop = (otherProp as NSURL).absoluteString
}
```

Comment: check the type of Obj.prop. does it have two question marks? Like - 'String??' for example